# SQL - select a list of lists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I have a table where each row may or may not be merged via a merge_id.

Its easy to jump in and grab all merged rows, where the merge_id column is not null. The thing is I want to output the merged rows together in one container on the client side.

I there any way for sql to return a collection for merged collections ?
Do I sort in ascending order of the merge ID and trust that its sequential ?

**EDIT**

```
 ________________________________________________
|id   | firstname      | lastName    |  merge_id |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |   jane         |   Doe       |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------|
| 2   |    John        |   Doe       |       1   |
-------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------|
| 3  |   max           |    payne    |     2     |
-------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------------------|
| 4   |   sub          |      zero   |      3    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So I want to query in such a way that I know that jane and max belong to different mergers.

Comment: Please add some simple example of your problem (sample data and desired output), as it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, merge_id 
FROM table t
ORDER BY t.merge_id
```

That would give you a record per person, and the merge_id will be ascending:

```
1 | Jane Doe 
1 | John Doe
2 | max payne
3 | sub zero
```

Otherwise, you can use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT merge_id , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname))
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.merge_id
ORDER BY t.merge_id
```

Which will give one record per merge_id:

```
1 | Jane Doe, John Doe
2 | max payne
3 | sub zero
```